# Get path of lazy loaded JS file from within the file?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I'm loading a script using something like

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);`

…what code can I put inside of that loaded JS file to get the URL of itself?

In other words: I use dom injection to load http://foo.com/foo.js.  From within foo.js, how do I get the URL http://foo.com/foo.js?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn’t possible reliably. Why do you need to do this? (And wouldn’t it be easier for the server to manage that?)

Comment: As far as reliability goes, I'm only running this on webkit browsers, so IE is not a concern.  
Basically, I want to load javascript files and call functions within them.  
  
I'm loading various javascript files from a cdn that can only serve flat files, so server-side scripting is out.  Which of these javascript files are loaded is determined at runtime, and their filenames are altered programmatically when they're copied to the cdn by code that's out of my control.  I want to use the filename to  create a dictionary that holds gateway objects that are registered by the loaded js files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the scriptElement object in your dom, then you should know the "scriptElement.src" - so inside foo.js you should know the source:

```
   alert(scriptElement.src);
```

Comment: That gives me an `Uncaught ReferenceError: scriptElement is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me here:

[javascript - get node reference to script tag that calls a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917836/javascript-get-node-reference-to-script-tag-that-calls-a-function)

The answer that requires you to throw an error in the loaded file, catch it, and then pass it to the global function in the loading page did the trick.  (It doesn't work in IE, but for my current project that is not a concern.)